# Can I learn Joomla 2.5 and Apply my knowledge on Joomla 3.6

Tags: joomla

I have Joomla programming ebook by Mark Dexter and Louis Landry published by year of 2012. The book is about 594 pages. Currently Joomla is at 3.6 I did some google search on difference between Joomla 2.5 and 3.6 but did not come to a conclusion if my knowledge gained from reading the ebook would apply on 3.6 with some modification.

I need someone advice on the matter that would save me time?

Any references to learning joomla 3.6 programming Components, Modules, Extensions and Plugins would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most things yes. There are some specific API changes and these are documented in the Joomla documentation site. You may want to ask for more feedback on the dedicated Joomla stack exchange site.